# Suddenly receiving firebase database error when logging in through app: " Evaluation error: NSURLErrorDomain: -1003"

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am currently working on an IOS app built through Swift on Xcode. Firebase packages are installed using Cocoapods, and all pods are updated. Additionally, I double-checked that the Plist and Google-Service Info files are correct.
This is the full error line I receive when logging into the app and trying to retrieve user information from the database:

> nw_proxy_resolver_create_parsed_array [C3.1.1 proxy pac] Evaluation
> error: NSURLErrorDomain: -1003

I am unable to figure out how to resolve this issue as there were no changes in my code and it was working beforehand perfectly.
I can provide code snippets if needed but since the app was working prior, I am assuming this isn't related to my code.

The only time I was able to solve this issue temporarily was to reset the package caches through XCode, allowing me to view posts and other content pulled from the firebase backend. Unfortunately, after I restarted the app, this solution did not work anymore, and the same error from above popped up. Since resetting the package caches worked initially, I am assuming there is no direct correlation between the error and my source code.

Does anyone have any idea as to ways I can solve this issue? It has prevented me from working on my app for several days now. Thanks for any help!

Update: After looking over my code one more time, I found that there was a missing dot in a line of code, leading to my IOS app not running. This did NOT solve the error of nw_proxy_resolver_create_parsed_array [C3.1.1 proxy pac] Evaluation error: NSURLErrorDomain: -1003, but since the app is working successfully, my problem is solved.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Assuming it's not your code can be problematic. For example, something in the back-end data could have changed that your code doesn't know how to handle; a missing field or perhaps **an array going out of bounds**. Please do some troubleshooting; step through the code line by line, examining the flow and vars along the way until you find something unexpected. Then post that code snippet and sample of your Firebase structure and we'll take a look. Also, doing research on errors can be [revealing](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nw_proxy_resolver_create_parsed_array)

Comment: @Jay thank you for the comment! I appreciate any help. I have researched the error NSURLErrorDomain -1003, both through the Apple documentation and through other similar questions on SO. I will go ahead and double-check my code to see if there is an array going out of bounds. The reason I assumed it wasn't involving my code was due to the fact the IOS app was temporarily working when I cleared the package caches. Once I double-check the code, I will post it here. Thank you again!

Comment: @Jay Thanks for the advice, after looking over the code, I was indeed missing a dot in a line of code, allowing my IOS app to work perfectly!